# Key value pair for flat data

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi I have a JavaScript array of objects for columns which is coming from MongoDB. Columns contains its Key and Value as an array . Here is my code

```
[  
   {  
      "F":"Age Min",
      "H":"Age Min",
      "L":"",
      "V":[  
         "1",
         "2",
         "3"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "F":"Age Max",
      "H":"Age Max",
      "L":"",
      "V":[  
         "12",
         "30",
         "4"
      ]
   }
]
```

What I want as an output is

```
[  
   {  
      "Age Min":1,
      "Age Max":12
   },
   {  
      "Age Min":2,
      "Age Max":30
   },
   {  
      "Age Min":3,
      "Age Max":4
   }
]
```

Need help , I am struggling to get the desired output.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = [  
   {  
      "F":"Age Min",
      "H":"Age Min",
      "L":"",
      "V":[  
         "1",
         "2",
         "3"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "F":"Age Max",
      "H":"Age Max",
      "L":"",
      "V":[  
         "12",
         "30",
         "4"
      ]
   }
];

var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var prop = input[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < prop.V.length; j++) {
    if (j >= output.length) { output[j] = {}; }
    var o = output[j];
    o[prop.F] = prop.V[j];
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: ES6 Version:  
let output = [];
input.map((value) => {
  value.V.map((v, index) => {
    if (index >= output.length) { output[index] = {}; }
    output[index][value.F] = value.V[index]
  });
});
console.log(output);

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the outer array and the inner arrays and build a new object with the transposed data.

```js
var array = [{ F: "Age Min", H: "Age Min", L: "", V: ["1", "2", "3"] }, { F: "Age Max", H: "Age Max", L: "", V: ["12", "30", "4"] }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.V.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][a.F] = b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

ES6 with a compact style.

```js
var array = [{ F: "Age Min", H: "Age Min", L: "", V: ["1", "2", "3"] }, { F: "Age Max", H: "Age Max", L: "", V: ["12", "30", "4"] }],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => (a.V.forEach((b, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[a.F] = b), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You always beat me to it by a few minutes :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to restructure your data:

```js
var data = [{
    "F": "Age Min",
    "H": "Age Min",
    "L": "",
    "V": ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {
    "F": "Age Max",
    "H": "Age Max",
    "L": "",
    "V": ["12", "30", "4"]
  }
]

var result = data.reduce(function(result, field, init) {
  field.V.forEach(function(value, i) {
    if (!init) result[i] = {}
    result[i][field.F] = +value
  })
  return result
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```